# Angularjs: Prevent dirty check on mouseenter/mouseleave event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-digest

In Angular, is there a way to prevent dirty check on such event?

Actually, my code in these handlers do not change the model so I don't want Angular to perform dirty check on these very often triggered event.

Comment: you can set pristine to inputs on handlers.

Comment: What do you mean by "prevent dirty check"? Do you mean, prevent a $digest cycle where Angular dirty-checks all $watched variables?

Comment: Can you details what are you trying to do in mouseenter and mouseleave? Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: I belive you asking this question for preformance, you can use scope.$digest instead of scope.$apply, if you belive this mouseover changed not effect the parent scope. look at this post for more details: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2596-case-study-using-scope-digest-as-a-performance-optimization-in-angularjs.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of your inputs using **Angular FormController** ([documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)).

You have these properties:

> - `$pristine` - True if user has not interacted with the form yet.
> - `$dirty` - True if user has already interacted with the form.

which means you don't need to worry about `mouseenter`/`mouseleave`.

Also, you can find this detailed tutorial on the matter:

http://mrbool.com/the-concepts-of-angularjs-forms/29117